# Is there a word that means "expressed using words", as opposed to an idea that is expressed through pictures?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Is there a word that means "expressed using words", as opposed to an idea that is expressed through pictures? I first thought of "articulate" or "explicit" but those aren't quite right.
(For context, I'm writing a paper that attempts to compare visual art, literature, and music and the differences in how they express their ideas.)

Comment: If you were not also discussing music, "composed" (as in *written composition*) could be a strong contender.

Comment: Is there a picture word meaning "expressed through pictures" that you are contrasting with? If it's "visual" or "pictoral", then what's wrong with "written" or "verbal"?

Answer (score 1):

"Verbal." And, before anyone says "that's just for spoken words," I give you [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verbal):

> Verbal: of, relating to, or consisting of words

Answer (score 0):

Old answer: **verbalized**

New answer:

Given the added context, I also like Phl3tch's answer, but I think simply

> **written**

fits your criteria. (And it's exceptionally explicit.)

Comment: I was more looking for a word that specifically refers to being written down. "Verbal" and "verbalize" are both too strongly associated with being spoken.